# Jest - Cannot find module 'source-map' from 'source-map-support.js'

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I've got the problem that I get the error:

```
Cannot find module 'source-map' from 'source-map-support.js'
Ran all test suites matching /Foo-test/i.
T:\public_html\testProj>jest Foo-test
FAIL  //XXXX.de/XXXX/Users/XXX/public_html/testProj/src/__tests__/Foo-test.js
? Test suite failed to runtml/testProj/src/__tests__/Foo-test.js
Cannot find module 'source-map' from 'source-map-support.js'
at Resolver.resolveModule (T:/public_html/testProj/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:221:17)
```

If I try to run a test with Jest.

My .babelrc looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"],
  "sourceMaps": "both",
  "plugins": [
    "add-module-exports",
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "source-map-support"
  ]
}
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "testproject",
  "version": "1.8.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "css-hot-loader": "^1.3.9",
    "eslint": "4.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.4.4-rc1",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "4.1.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "source-map": "^0.7.3",
    "webpack": "^4.0.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.6.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-accessible-accordion": "^2.4.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-string-replace": "^0.4.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sinon": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "build": "webpack --colors --profile --progress --env.mode production",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/ --ext .js,.jsx",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ]
  }
}
```

The test itself seems to be ok, but I get the error nevertheless.

I tried different solutions:

-Some people say it would be necessary to add these configs to the package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ]
  }
```

But I had no luck with that either. Can someone help here?

Answer (score 9):

Hit this issue when using a Jest test runner in VS Code.
Taking a pointer from https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6880#issuecomment-441499110, I noticed that my `jest.config.js` contained

```
    moduleDirectories: ["<rootDir>/node_modules", "<rootDir>/ClientApp"]
```

Changing it to

```
    moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "ClientApp"]
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I resolve the problem by running the project and node in the same drive.

i.e. previously my code is put in `Q:/` drive, and my nodejs is install in `C:/` drive.
and it keeps saying `Cannot find module 'source-map' from 'source-map-support.js'` when I run jest.
once after I open my project in `C:/`, then it works.

Comment: so i think u need to move your project from `T:/` to `C:/` where node will usually install.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have:

```
moduleDirectories: ["node_modules"]
```

not:

```
moduleDirectories: ["/node_modules/"]
```

and don't omit the node_modules here.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a new situation,another possibility is an error during installation, reinstall `ts-node` to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

FYI this just happened to me at work. I'm not enough of an expert to understand what's going on under the hood, but the root of my problem was that I had my project running inside webpack in dev mode in a primary terminal, at the same time I was trying to run the tests in a 2nd terminal.

Once I stopped the dev server, the tests ran just fine afterwards.

Comment: why would this work?